# Regex to search for base url only

Tags: regex

I am beginner in regex, I have a list url's such as

```
https://www.apple.com/
https://www.apple.com
https://www.apple.com/
https://www.google.com/result
https://www.google.co.in/
https://www.google.co.in/data
```

I am trying to write a regex which can return only url's like

```
https://www.apple.com/
https://www.apple.com
https://www.apple.com/
https://www.google.co.in/
```

I tried to build the regex like this :

```
^\s*[A-Z]*://(.*"?(com|in)"?/?$)
```

But in above regex there is a chance that I might miss other domains like us,eu etc.

Please let me know what can be correct regex for this, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Like this? `^https?://www\.(?:apple\.com/?|google\.(?:com|co\.in)/\S*)$` https://regex101.com/r/Aojssg/1

Comment: This is hardcode regex, what if there are other websites.

Comment: I see, like this? `^https?://\S+\.(?:com|co\.in)\b/?\S*$` https://regex101.com/r/Q4roJV/1

Comment: With your regex we might miss domains like us,eu etc. The same has mentioned in the question.

Comment: Should there be `www.` present? Using `^https?://\S+` will match for example, but are there any specific rules to it?

Comment: As this is a very common task, there are usually modules available, e.g. `urllib` in `Python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **extract** base URLs try this:

```
https?://[^/]+
```

This matches `https://` with optional `s` literally and any characters that are **not** `/`, thus effectively stopping at the URL base delimiter.

If you want to **match** base URLs rather than extract them, you can use *optional* `/` and the string end-position anchor `$`:

```
https?://[^/]+/?$
```

Comment: The above regex will return true for https://www.google.com/result but in my case it should not.

Comment: I don't know what language/regex flavor you are using. In my case it's R and the result is `"https://www.google.com"` And since you speak of returning TRUE it seems like you're not extracting but using something like `grep`, which will obviously return TRUE

Comment: Basically I am using sublime's regex search, my goal is to find these entries and replace them, with your regex we might end up with replacing this https://www.google.com/result which should not be done.

Comment: With this regex, we will skip https://www.apple.com

Comment: Cool, it will work thanks, but just an edit if you want it http://[^/]+/?$|https://[^/]+/?$, will be match http also, but if you have some other way to test this, you can let me know. But thanks again mate.

Comment: You can make the `s`optional; see edit. If my work was helpful please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann This will match invalid web URLs because it doesn't check if a domain is given. E.g. `http://+` will be match!

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following. Generic solution, Based on your shown samples.

```
^https?:\/\/www\.(?:\w+(\.com|\.co\.in))\/?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/c1TlZR/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^https?                ##Checking if it starts from http s is optional here.
:\/\/www\.             ##Matching ://www. here.
(?:                    ##Starting non capturing group here.
  \w+(\.com|\.co\.in)  ##Matching word character one more occurrences here, followed by .com OR .co.in here.
)                      ##Closing non-capturing group here.
\/?$                   ##Matching /(as an optional) at the end of url.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** completely based on your shown samples, please try following.

```
^https?:\/\/www\.(?:apple\.com\/?|google\.(?:com|co\.in))\/?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/sVt9hi/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^https?:                   ##Checking if value starts from http s is optional with :
\/\/www\.                  ##Matching //www. here.
(?:                        ##Starting a non-capturing group here.
   apple\.com\/?|google\.  ##matching apple.com OR google . here.
   (?:com|co\.in)          ##In a non-capturing group matching com OR co.in
)                          ##Closing non-capturing group here.
\/?$                       ##Matching /(as an optional) at the end of url.
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex does the job:

```
^\s*(https?:\/\/[a-z0-9_.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}\/?)
```

It must be set to **case insensitive** or you must allow uppercase everywhere (including `https`)!

```
^\s*             # Allow whitespaces at the beginning
(                # Starting a group where the URL should be in ($1)
https?:\/\/      # url starts with "http://" or "https://" (\ normally not needed)
[a-z0-9_.-]+     # Multible signs in url allowed ("." included)
\.[a-z]{2,3}     # The domain name at the end
\/?              # At the a "/" is allowed
)                # end of the group
```

Then you can take the result of group 1 (`$1`). The last "/" is included if available.

[image: Graphic by debuggex.com]
https://www.debuggex.com/

Look at [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) too, there it is detailed explained.

Comment: The above regex will return true for https://www.google.com/result but in my case it should not.

Comment: @Logan To extract somthing, it must be true at first. I have added an explanation.